# android: Email an XML string (in-memory file) as an attachment

Tags: android, email-attachments

How can I email an XML string (or an in-memory file) in android as a file attachment without actually creating a physical File?

I want to just build an XML data string (backup data) and have the user email it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Intent.ACTION_SEND, I am almost sure that the simple answer is that you can't.

If you must, then you will have to implement your own mail sender using, perhaps, an Android port of JavaMail or you can build a new one from scratch.